# Read math functions from file and calculate

Tags: c, cuda

I'm creating program which will read model described by math functions from file into memory. I need to make these functions invokable. Is there any other way to achive it instead of implementing RPN ? Performance is the most important factor.

Maybe something like creating and compiling functions during runtime, after reading model from file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CUDA currently only has JIT compilation for device code written in PTX assembly code. So your only "native" JIT option would be to have your code translate the functions into PTX code and compile them.

Realistically, your best option would be to write your front end in Python and use [PyCUDA](http://mathema.tician.de/software/pycuda/), which includes some very powerful metaprogramming and JIT compilation features, or to use OpenCL, which has native C99 JIT compilation, at the expense of an uglier and more verbose host API and a lack of C++ language support.

Comment: Looks great. I need to parse model once and fill template, then I can do heavy computational things much faster than using RPN.